# Is it possible to inform previous user of application in google play store regarding completly new application not a updated version?

Tags: android, google-play, publish

I lost my certificate(key), so I am uploading a new application. The problem is that the previous application already has more than 10,000 downloads, so how do I inform them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution you have is to update the description and hope that some people will read it.

This can be done from your Play Store console and does not require the signing key.

If you generate a new key, you won't be able to update the old one and inform your users.
Maybe you can contact the Play Store team, but I doubt they will answer..

Comment: how to update the description if i don't have key(certificate) information of already application is there in Google store

Comment: From the Play Store console, where you uploaded the apk.. You don't need the key to do so. You have at least access to the console I guess???

Comment: If i am doing it, how the people get to know?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a new release.keystore in order to sign your app and submit to Google Play. You could just change your current app to a higher version, sign it with a new keystore, and publish as a new app. But you'll still have to remove the old app from Google Play. That leaves the new app as the one people should install. The only downside with that is that the current users will have to uninstall the old and install the new in order to "upgrade."

Comment: change your current app to a higher version, sign it with a new keystore and publish as a new app.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get your key back with Brute Force.

Comment: for Brute forse any software available?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android-keystore-password-recover/ or https://github.com/BluePyth/android-keystore-recovery/blob/master/README.md. If you know that you key has more than 6 chars then Brute Force wont help you as it would take too long(~>170days for 7chars key).

Comment: @user1337...but i dont have my certificate

Comment: Ok sry I thought you lost only the key ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you're running ads on the app, you can create a house ad that links to your new application.  Then, give the house ad 100% allocation so all your users will see your new app instead of the regular ads.

Comment: I have ads in new application but not in Old application. though it is possible you are talking.